# Setting values to a specific element in an array of dictionary overrides all values in array

Tags: dictionary, julia

I'm trying to assign a specific value to a specific location in an array of dictionaries.
the assignment overrides all values in array - why?

```
a = fill(Dict("example" => 0.),3)
a[1]["example"] = 1.
println(a)
```

'''
output is

```
[Dict("example" => 1.0), Dict("example" => 1.0), Dict("example" => 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of `fill` and it's described in [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill).

> If x is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object

## Use a Array comprehension

I suggest using [array comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions) for this purpose.

```
julia> a = [Dict("example" => 0.) for _ in 1:3]
julia> a[1]["example"] = 1.                                                                                           
1.0
julia> println(a)
[Dict("example" => 1.0), Dict("example" => 0.0), Dict("example" => 0.0)]
```

## Alternative `map` solution

If you really dislike list comprehensions you could use `map` to achieve the same solution by instantiating multiple instances of the same looking dictionary.

```
julia> b = map(x -> Dict("example" => 0.), 1:3)
3-element Vector{Dict{String, Float64}}:
 Dict("example" => 0.0)
 Dict("example" => 0.0)
 Dict("example" => 0.0)

julia> b[1]["example"] = 2.0
2.0

julia> println(b)
[Dict("example" => 2.0), Dict("example" => 0.0), Dict("example" => 0.0)]
```